# How to assign and retrieve values in array with if condition in php

Tags: php

I need to assign working days for years with if condition, like if year is 1995 then 240 working days, if year is 1996 242 working days.and so on.. instead of giving if condition to every year, is it possible to store values in array form with if condition?
What tried is

```
if ( $_GET['year_attend'] == 1995) { $work_days = '140';}
if ( $_GET['year_attend'] == 1996) { $work_days = '142';}
```

Comment: Use an associative array.

Comment: `[1995 => 140, 1996 => 142, ...]`

Comment: sir pls explain with full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This completely depends on how you define your off days.

If you assume that there are two off-days of a week (e.g. Saturday & Sunday) and you want to calculate all number of working days except the off-days then -

```php
function isLeapYear($year) {
    return ($year % 4 == 0) && ($year % 100 !== 0 || $year % 400 === 0);
}

function getWorkingDays($year) {
    $totalDays = isLeapYear($year) ? 366 : 365;
    $firstDay = (new DateTime("01-01-$year"));
    $offDays = ['Saturday', 'Sunday'];

    $leaves = 0;
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

    for ($day = 1; $day <= $totalDays; $day++) {
        // Check if the day is a off-day or not. If off-day then increment the leave count.
        if (in_array($firstDay->format('l'), $offDays)) {
            $leaves++;
        }

        // Shift the day to the next date by adding one day interval.
        $firstDay->add($interval);    
    }

    // Calculate the total working days by subtracting the leaves from the total days.
    $totalWorkDays = $totalDays - $leaves;

    return $totalWorkDays;
}

$data = [];

for ($i = 1994; $i <= 2020; $i++) {
    $data[$i] = getWorkingDays($i);
}

var_dump($data);
```

If you have a list of other `off-days` then inside the loop check if the date is included in the off-day list or not. If included then increment the leave count.